# resize background in auto width div

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I create Any div in auto width with single image background. in act this worked but There is a small problem. end of right images not overlapped.

HTML :

```
<div class="home"><span><em>40</em></span></div>
```

CSS :

```
.home{
            border:none;
            background:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:auto;
               overflow:visible;                    
            text-align:center;    
            white-space:nowrap;    
            height:40px;
            line-height:34px;   display:inline-block;        
            }
        .home span, .home em{
            display:inline-block;
            height:40px;
            line-height:34px;            
            margin:0;
            color:#954b05;
            }    
        .home span{
            padding-left:15px;
            background:url(http://www.uploadup.com/di-GRW2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
            }    
        .home em{
            font-style:normal;
            padding-right:20px;
            background:url(http://www.uploadup.com/di-GRW2.png) no-repeat 100% 0;}
```

See E.X In Action : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/33m4p/4/)
My Problem : [HERE](http://www.uploadup.com/di-FIYW.png)

Comment: this is my problem : http://www.uploadup.com/di-FIYW.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing that because the corners of your PNG are transparent. Either make them white (same as background) or use another method. Most modern browsers allow you to do rounded borders via CSS now (with the exception of IE).

Answer (score 1):

you can make the same curve box as per your image with css3 here is small css for you to make curve box and compatible with all browsers:-

```
.box {
border:1px solid #dadada;
width:50px;
height:50px;    
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

**check the live demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/ZysQa/3/

i have used **behavior** hack for ie support border radius property so for ie border details you can read this article.....[cross browsers css3 border radius](http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/)